# css variables not working with react testing library

Tags: css, reactjs, react-testing-library, css-variables, react-testing

What I am doing is testing the dark mode feature. There is a button to toggle dark mode. When it clicks, the `onClick` event will trigger and the css variables values will be changed to dark mode. **But when i check the background color of an textarea, that is not changed. I checked that the dark mode button `onClick` function is triggering successfully.**

**The test case :-**

```
it("should change the background color when dark mode enabled", () => {
    render(<App />);
    const darkModeBtn = screen.getByText(/dark mode/i);
    const textArea = screen.getByTestId("text-area");

    darkModeBtn.click();

    expect(textArea).toHaveStyle("background-color: rgb(39, 39, 39)"); // rgb(39, 39, 39) is equal to #272727
});
```

**The button element :-**

```
<button className="menu-btn btn" onClick={toggleTheme}>
     Dark Mode
</button>
```

**The `toggleTheme` function from button element `onClick` :-**

```
function toggleTheme() {
  const currentTheme: string =
    document.documentElement.getAttribute("data-theme") ||
    localStorage.getItem("theme") ||
    "dark";

  if (currentTheme === "light") {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
  } else if (currentTheme === "dark") {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
  }
}
```

*To get more info about the code :- **https://github.com/Muhammed-Rahif/Notepad***

#### Is there any problem with css variables in react-testing-library or we cannot test css variables related test in RTL? If can how it will be?!

---

***From My research I found these two issues in Github :-***

- [*.toHaveStyle() does not get font-size w/ css variable*](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/322)
- [*Does Not Apply CSS Custom Properties*](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1895)

Comment: If I am not wrong it's because react testing library is using a simplified browser which has many CSS and other layout related features not implemented.